# How to compare modified array against original (in Lua)?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, lua

A bit pseudo code first:

```lua
local array = {
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d",
    "e",
    "f",
    "g",
}
```

Now, create some data, which stores important information about the original array. It could be just to copy the whole array, but since i don't know what the fastest way is to solve my problem, I leave that open.

```lua
local info = createinfo(array)
```

Now create a new version of the array, either with `table.remove/insert()` or just create a new array with the original elements. So no shenanigans with overriding `table.insert/remove()`.

```lua
local array = {
    "a",
    "b",
    "d",
    "e",
    "f",
    "c",
}
```

Find out what changed (specifications below)

```lua
local changes = calculatechanges(array, info)
```

What do I wanna find out?

1. What Element has been moved? (e.g. `"c"`)
2. What Element has been removed? (e.g. `"g"`)
3. I'm not interested where the element has been moved to.

How do i find that out, if it is even possible?
And what is the fastest way, since my original problem is time critical (both `createchanges()` and `calculatechanges()`)?

P.S. By the way, I'm working with Lua 5.1 if thats important.

Edit:
As "change" I define the following:
What is the minimum amount of "move x from index i to j", to transform the original array into the modified version?

Another Edit:
Probably I'm looking for a similair implementation of the Levenshtein distance. However, I need to know, which elements have to be substituted, not (only) the distance.

Comment: `c` and `d` have been swapped.  So, `What Element has been moved?`  Is it `c` or `d`?

Comment: Thats actually a good question. I'll edit my question to make it even more precise. I added a few more elements to the list, so it is clear, that I want the minimum amount of changes.

Comment: What do you define as a `change`, if it is a change in index then that is true of `d`, `e`, and `f` in addition to `c`. for example: `"a","b","c","d"` -> `"a","c","b","d"` how would you describe that change? and how is it different from `"a","c","d","b"` note that `c` has "moved" in both cases.

Comment: @Nifim Ok I think I now understand, whats unclear about my question. As change I define the following:
What are the minimum movements in units of "move x from index i to index j" to transform the original array into the modified version.
Does that clearify my question? I hope I didn't made it more confusing.

Comment: Now it sounds like you are looking for a way to calculate edit distance, e.g., [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Comment: @exnihilo It seems like you are right. That might be, what I'm trying to implement. However, i not only want to know how many changes have been made, but what elements have been moved, since i need to apply them on another dataset and that is the time intensive part of my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an solution, I inverted the arrays to allow for simplified index look up.
I then use a while loop to selectively increment the index of `a1` or `a2`.

```lua
function diff(a1, a2)

  local added = {}
  local moved = {}
  local removed = {}

  local a1IndexOf = {}
  for i, v in ipairs(a1)do
    a1IndexOf[v] = i
  end

  local a2IndexOf = {}
  for i, v in ipairs(a2)do
    a2IndexOf[v] = i
  end

  local index1 = 1
  local index2 = 1
  while(index1 <= #a1) do
    local value1 = a1[index1]
    local value2 = a2[index2]

    if value1 == value2 then
      index1 = index1 + 1
      index2 = index2 + 1

    elseif a2IndexOf[value1] == nil then   
      removed[value1] = true
      index1 = index1 + 1

    elseif moved[value1] then
      index1 = index1 + 1

    elseif moved[value2] then
      index2 = index2 + 1

    elseif a1IndexOf[value2] < a2IndexOf[value1] then
      moved[value1] = true
      index1 = index1 + 1
    else
      moved[value2] = true
      index2 = index2 + 1
    end
  end

  print("\nElements Moved:")
  for v in pairs(moved) do
    print("\t" .. v)
  end
  print("\nElements Removed:")
  for v in pairs(removed) do
    print("\t" .. v)
  end
end
```

Some example inputs and results:

```lua
local array = {
  "a",
  "b",
  "c",
}

local info = {

  "a",
  "c",
  "b",
}
```

```
Elements Moved:
    c

Elements Removed:
```

```lua
local array = {
  "a",
  "b",
  "c",
}

local info = {

  "a",
  "c",

}
```

```
Elements Moved:

Elements Removed:
    b
```

Comment: Having just read your code, it seems like time complexity is proportional to N. Is that the Levensthein Algorithm?

Comment: @Sewbacca i think it is more of a symmetric difference that also includes changes in position, not sure if there is name for such an algorithm

Comment: It is necessary to review every item in the original array, that is if we can not make records of the changes when you make them. Levensthein is O(nm) this i believe is something like O(2n + 2m)

Comment: If you use OP sample input of `{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'}` --> `{'a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'c'}` the result of `diff` is that 'c' has been moved and 'g' has been removed. But, wouldn't you say that 'd', 'e', and 'f' have also been moved? The only elements that remain at their original indices are 'a' and 'b'.

Comment: @exnihilo according to the OP, no. they wanted this specific behavior

Comment: It is unclear exactly what OP wants, but OP says: "_1. What element has been moved? 2. What element has been removed?_", and later "_what is the minimum amount of 'move x from index i to index j'_".

Comment: OP also says in a comment that they need to be able to apply this information to "_another dataset and that is the time intensive part of my program._"

Comment: I agree it may still be somewhat unclear, my understanding is the OP is using `table.insert` and `table.remove` to make the changes and wants to know the minimum uses of the functions to make the changes.

Comment: Yes, the mention of `table.insert` adds some confusion. But, I don't see how to get from OP original array to OP transformed array with `table.remove` and `table.insert` knowing only that 'g' is removed and 'c' is moved. At the least you would need a `move` function that deletes 'c' from the sequence and then inserts it at the end.

Comment: I gave you best answer, since I really think that will solve my problem, but currently I am too busy to test that. However I didn't want to let this question hang open in the air.